# Advantages & Disadvantages Object Storage vs File Storage for a Subversion repository?

Tags: svn, object, storage

I'm new to Subversion and Object Storage concepts. I'm trying to understand whether storing a Subversion repository on an Object Storage solution is possible and also whether it would be advantageous to do so (as opposed to using traditional File Storage)? Possibly having application servers using NFS to access the Subversion repository share with the repository files located on Object Storage.

Thanks in advance,

Jim